# Custom category template is displaying all categories

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, categories

Here is the template. My category slug is 'news' and category id is 40. Ive titled the php file category-news.php and category-40.php. Both files give the correct template but it is displaying all categories when all I want is single category. What do I have to change in order to display a single category?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Category PAGE
*/ 
get_header();?>

<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $blog_style = $hana_post_meta['blog_style'];
    if($blog_style=='fluid') $hana_page_options['layout'] = 'full';
?>
<div class="blog-container <?php echo $blog_style;?>-blog">

    <div id="content" class="<?php echo ($blog_style!='fluid')?vintage_content_class():'';?>">

        <?php
        //query posts
        $postsPerPage=hana_get_opt('_post_per_page_on_blog')==''?5:hana_get_opt('_post_per_page_on_blog');
        $excludeCat=explode(',',hana_get_opt('_exclude_cat_from_blog'));
        query_posts(array(
            'category__not_in' => $excludeCat,
            'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
            'posts_per_page' => hana_get_opt('_post_per_page_on_blog')
        ));

        $blog_loop = array();
        $blog_loop['layout'] = $hana_page_options['layout'];
        $blog_loop['column'] = $hana_post_meta['blogcolumn'];

        get_template_part( 'loop', $blog_style );

        wp_reset_query();?>

    </div>

    <?php get_sidebar();?>
    <?php vintage_get_addtional_products(); ?>
</div><?php

endwhile; endif;?>    

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What do I have to change to display a single category and not all with this template?

Answer (score 0):

`query_posts()` needs to go before The Loop. [See the Wordpress Function Reference for query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Usage).